# How to combine parent linq expression with children expression through Any function

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern

I have an ef model like this

```
    public class Parent
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Child> Children{ get; set; }
    }

    public class Child
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Parent Parent { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
    }
```

and i have two Expressions

```
Expression<Func<Parent,bool>> parentExpression = ...
Expression<Func<Child,bool>> childExpression = ...
```

that i have to combine like this

```
IQueryable<Parent> queryable = MyParentRepository.All().AsNoTracking();
parentExpression = parentExpression.And(p=>p.Chidlren.Any(c=>childExpression.Compile()(c)); //this is the problem
var results = queryable = queryable.Where(parentExpression).ToList();
```

`And()` is an extension method for `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` that already works

But when ef-core translates the queryable i obtain the error

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Child> ....' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Is there a way to combine the Expressions without compiling `childExpression`?

Thank you in advance

**EDIT (found a possible solution)**

Since `IQueryable.Any` expects an Expression, differently from `IEnumerable.Any` that expects a Func, I tried this that works

```
IQueryable<Parent> queryable = MyParentRepository.All().AsNoTracking();
parentExpression = parentExpression.And(p=>p.Chidlren.AsQueryable().Any(childExpression); //<----
var results = queryable = queryable.Where(parentExpression).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is long story with EF. Without additional extensions it will not work.

Popular answer for this is [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit), as I know latest version should handle `Compile()`

```cs
IQueryable<Parent> queryable = MyParentRepository.All()
   .AsExpandable() // important call
   .AsNoTracking();
```

Then your query should work.

Also LINQKit has another option for that `Invoke`. Don't forget to call `AsExpandable`.

```cs
parentExpression = parentExpression
   .And(p => p.Chidlren.Any(c => childExpression.Invoke(c));
```

Comment: Thank You, I was about to try LINQKit but maybe i found another cleaner way to accomplish (see my edit)

Comment: Yes, it should work. But if you are trying to use such predicates inside Lambda body, it will fail.

Comment: Yes, You are right but in my specific case there is no need to use a Lambda body

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote on my question, since `IQueryable.Any` takes an Expression as argument, differently from `IEnumerable.Any` that takes a Func, I tried this

```
IQueryable<Parent> queryable = MyParentRepository.All().AsNoTracking();
parentExpression = parentExpression.And(p=>p.Chidlren.AsQueryable().Any(childExpression); //<----
var results = queryable = queryable.Where(parentExpression).ToList();
```

It works perfectly and apparently with no drawbacks